# Rails - LoadError (cannot load such file -- json_web_token)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rails-api

I'm building a small API with rails for registering and logging in users. The rails API app makes two post requests: one for registering the user & the other for logging in the user. The post request for registering the user works fine, but the problem is that the API request for logging in the user is not reading the json_web_token file properly. I keep getting a 500 internal server error whenever I error whenever I make a post request for logging in the user. This is the exact error I get:

Started POST "/users/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-16 13:54:15 +0200

LoadError (cannot load such file -- ./lib/json_web_token):

app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:1:in`'
Started POST "/users/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-16 13:54:28 +0200

I tried changing the file name of json_web_token to match exactly the name of the file when I'm requiring it in application controller, but nothing change. And I tried calling the whole path of the file, but still no luck. Any help would much appreciated.

This is my application_controller:

```html
require 'json_web_token' 
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
    
end
```

This is my users_controller:

```html
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def create
        user = User.new(user_params)
      
        if user.save
          render json: {status: 'User created successfully'}, status: :created
        else
          render json: { errors: user.errors.full_messages }, status: :bad_request
        end
    end
      

    def login
        user = User.find_by(email: params[:email].to_s.downcase)
      
        if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
            auth_token = JsonWebToken.encode({user_id: user.id})
            render json: {auth_token: auth_token}, status: :ok
        else
          render json: {error: 'Invalid username / password'}, status: :unauthorized
        end
    end


      private
      
    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

This is my json_web_token file:

```html
require 'jwt'

class JsonWebToken
  # Encodes and signs JWT Payload with expiration
  def self.encode(payload)
    payload.reverse_merge!(meta)
    JWT.encode(payload, Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base)
  end

  # Decodes the JWT with the signed secret
  def self.decode(token)
    JWT.decode(token, Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base)
  end

  # Validates the payload hash for expiration and meta claims
  def self.valid_payload(payload)
    if expired(payload) || payload['iss'] != meta[:iss] || payload['aud'] != meta[:aud]
      return false
    else
      return true
    end
  end

  # Default options to be encoded in the token
  def self.meta
    {
      exp: 7.days.from_now.to_i,
      iss: 'issuer_name',
      aud: 'client',
    }
  end

  # Validates if the token is expired by exp parameter
  def self.expired(payload)
    Time.at(payload['exp']) < Time.now
  end
end
```

And this is my gem file:

```html
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
# gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'jwt'
# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use Rack CORS for handling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), making cross-origin AJAX possible
# gem 'rack-cors'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: Please include the full error message in your question when asking about an error. In this case the error is about it not being able to find your json_web_token file, so its exact path is worth mentioning too.

Comment: I changed the file name by removing all underscores & put the entire path of the file like this: require './lib/jsonwebtoken' . But I'm still getting a 500 internal server error. The exact error is this:  Started POST "/users/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-16 13:54:15 +0200
  
LoadError (cannot load such file -- ./lib/json_web_token):
  
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
Started POST "/users/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-16 13:54:28 +0200

Comment: Can you set this in `application.rb` -> `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]` and the filename under the `lib` is `json_web_token.rb` right ?

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna yes the file jsonwebtoken.rb is under lib. How should I set this? You mean I should put this command in the terminal?

Comment: Can you rename the file to `json_web_token.rb`, if it is `jsonwebtoken.rb` and then in `application.rb`, add this line `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]`

Comment: @Kedgarnag for the info. But not it cannot locate the gem file when I bundle install. Why is that?

Comment: Why do you have `jsonwebtoken.rb` file in your `lib` directory ?

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna Never Mind what I said in the last comment. Now it cannot locate jwt. Error: LoadError (cannot load such file -- jwt). Thanks again and looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Where should jsonwebtoken.rb file be then?

Comment: The [gem](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt) already provides the method you have defined in your `jsonwebtoken.rb`. Are you trying to override them ? If not, I don't see a point in having that file.

Comment: Also, can you add `require jwt` in `UsersController.rb` and replace `JsonWebToken.encode({user_id: user.id})` with `JWT.encode({user_id: user.id})`

Comment: I think I am following the same tutorial and have the same exact issue. Also, why would we need to require jwt in the Users controller, since it inherits from Applicationcontroller?